# Android:Footer with Linear Layout comes up when Soft Key Board is open

Tags: android

My app contains header,edittext,listview and footer 
It works fine...but when soft keyboard is open for edittext my footer comes up.

I had also set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest.

my layout is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/middle_bg"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/header1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<include
android:id="@+id/header2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
layout="@layout/header" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tbllayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/header1"
>

<TableRow
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:background="@drawable/tit_bg" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/lbltit"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Registered Websites"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnAddNewRege"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:background="@drawable/plus"
android:gravity="left" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<View
 android:id="@+id/vwhr1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="10dip"
 android:layout_span="2" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/roundedtextview"
android:hint="Search"
android:textSize="13dp"
android:width="280sp"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSearchMain"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/search"
android:gravity="center" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<View
android:id="@+id/vwhr"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="10dip"
android:layout_span="2" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/tblftr"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
>

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/btnpanel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/black"
> 

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSetting"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/settings"
android:width="40dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnAboutUs"
android:background="@drawable/about_us"
android:width="100dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnFeedback"
android:background="@drawable/feedback"
android:width="100dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow> 
<include
 android:id="@+id/include1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 layout="@layout/footer" />
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
 android:id="@+id/lst"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_above="@id/tblftr"
 android:layout_below="@id/tbllayout"
 android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      >
 </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

pls guide

Thanks & Regards
Mita

Answer (score 0):

You could try and put your RelativeLayout in a `ScrollView`. This might not worked as intended if the `ListView` doesn't fill the screen since you would have to declare `layout_width="wrap_content"` for your `RelativeLayout` inside the `ScrollView` and that would bring your footer right bellow the `ListView`.

Try it and see if it fits your model.